# Web Application Performance Test(WAPT)

Tags: testing, performance-testing, automated-tests

I encountered a tool called WAPT which is a paid tool but comes with 30 days trial period.
I tried to search for the same on Internet but could find only  one or two links that doesn't give me a good idea about the capability of the tool.

Can anyone help me out of this by providing me any knowledge they possess regarding this tool.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) as an open source alternative to WAPT.

Comment: Pangea, that I know...but if u can help me with WAPT, that would be really great!